# method selector on one of many interceptors for a service registered in Castle.Windsor

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, aop, castle-dynamicproxy, interceptor

Using Castle.Windsor, how would I go about adding a IProxyGenerationHook or selector for one of several interceptors defined for a specific service. For example consider the following component registration:

```
 container.Register( _
    Component.For(Of IDataLoader) _
    .ImplementedBy(Of sqlldrDataLoader) _
    .Interceptors(Of LoggingInterceptor, FancySchmancyInterceptor))
```

The IDataLoader service has several methods. I want the following:
a) LoggingInterceptor will intercept every method.
b) FancySchmancyInterceptor should only intercept a subset of methods as defined in a selector of some description.

Many thanks,
Ryan.

Answer (score 1):

```
.SelectInterceptorsWith(s => s.Service<YourSelectorComponent>())
```